# Angular For Each loop with post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a post request with a angular.forEach loop, and then resolve a single promise with $q.all()...

This is how I have it set up:

```
angular.module('dataApp')
  .factory('UserService', function () {
    var User = $resource(ENV.API_URL + '/user/:email', {
      email: '@email'
    }, {
      add: {
        method: 'POST',
        url: ENV.API_URL + '/user/:email/medication/:medicationId',
        params: {
          email: '@email',
          dataId: '@medicationId'
        }
      }
    });

    User.addData = function (dataList) {
      var promiseArray = [];

      angular.forEach(dataList, function (data) {

        User.add({
          email: currentUser.email,
          dataId: data._id
        }).$promise.then(function success(response) {
          promiseArray.push(response.$promise);
        }, function error(response) {
          promiseArray.push(response.$promise);
          promiseArray.push(response.$promise);
        });
      });

      return $q.all(promiseArray);
    };
  });
```

When I try to push the promises into my promiseArray, my array is filled with empty quotes (e.g. console.log(promiseArray) ==> ["", ""]). Am I missing something?

Comment: What does response.$promise look like when you put in a break point?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `add`? There is `save` for that cases.

Anyway, try this:

```
promiseArray.push(User.add({
                      email: currentUser.email,
                      dataId: data._id
                 }).$promise);
```